# Xcode slide and delete

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

This is my code for a task recorder. It works fine I just want to but the slide and delete feature in my cells. Like what you can do in the music or email applications. How can I edit my current code so that each cell that is added can be slid over and then the delete button pops up. I have seen example of the code but I do not understand how to integrate it into mine.

My .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NSString *docPath(void); 

@interface BNRAppDelegate : UIResponder 
<UIApplicationDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{

    UITableView *taskTable;
    UITextField *taskField;
    UIButton *insertButton;
    UIButton *clearButton;

    NSMutableArray *tasks;
}

- (void)addTask:(id)sender;
- (void)takeTask:(id)sender;


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

This is my .m

```
#import "BNRAppDelegate.h"


NSString *docPath()
{
    NSArray *pathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                            NSUserDomainMask,
                                                            YES);
    return [[pathList objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.td" ];
}    

@implementation BNRAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

#pragma mark - Application delegate callbacks

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:                 (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSArray *plist = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:docPath()];
    if (plist)
    {
        tasks = [plist mutableCopy];
    }
    else
    {
        tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    CGRect windowFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIWindow *theWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:windowFrame];
    [self setWindow:theWindow];

    CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 380);
    CGRect fieldFrame = CGRectMake(5, 40, 180, 31);
    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(190, 40, 60, 31);
    CGRect clearFrame = CGRectMake(255, 40 , 60, 30); 


    taskTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [taskTable setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    [taskTable setDataSource:self];


    taskField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:fieldFrame];
    [taskField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [taskField setPlaceholder:@"Type a task, tap Insert"];


    insertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [insertButton setFrame:buttonFrame];
    [insertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addTask:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [insertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [insertButton setTitle:@"Insert" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    clearButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [clearButton setFrame:clearFrame];
    [clearButton addTarget:self action:@selector(takeTask:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [clearButton setTitle:@"Clear" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


     //For Clear make simular to ^^^ then add void. In Void use the variable t.               

    [[self window] addSubview:taskTable];
    [[self window] addSubview:taskField];
    [[self window] addSubview:insertButton];
    [[self window] addSubview:clearButton];

    [[self window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
- (void)addTask:(id)sender
{
    NSString *t=[taskField text];

    if ([t isEqualToString:@""]) {
        return;
    }

    [tasks addObject:t];
    [taskTable reloadData];
    [taskField setText:@""];
    [taskField resignFirstResponder];
} 

- (void)takeTask:(id)sender
{
    //LEARN ABOUT NSMUTABLEARRAYS AND HOW TO TAKE DADA FROM THEM
    [tasks removeAllObjects];
    [taskTable reloadData];
    [tasks writeToFile:docPath()
            atomically:YES];
}


#pragma mark - Table View management

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tasks count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    UITableViewCell *c= [taskTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (!c) {
        c= [[ UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    NSString *item = [tasks objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[c textLabel] setText:item];

    return c;
} 


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [tasks writeToFile:docPath()
            atomically:YES];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [tasks writeToFile:docPath()
            atomically:YES];
}

@end
```

This is what im trying but it doesn't work:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)table commitEditingStyle:       (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
          [tasks removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Comment: please learn how to use google and/or search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, add the following function

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return YES;
}
```

And

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)table commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
         //Go ahead and delete the row data now
    }
}
```

In function commitEditingStyle, you will have now to remove the actual cell data
For example if you have an NSMutableArray That contains the cell data
You now have to delete the actual object from it
Like the following
[arr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Thanks @OmarAbdelhafith. When i slide the delete button does appear but when I press the delete button nothing happens...

Comment: Thanks for the help. My NSMutableArray is called "tasks".  Look at my edit, that is what I tried but it doesnt work.  thank you for the help

Comment: If that is a question, then yes you should do that.

Comment: Yes sorry my fault, please write the following
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)table commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
         [tasks removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

Comment: Please try it and let me know :)

Comment: Pleas also dont forget to upvote and or accept the answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: I get an error: No know class method for selector 'deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:with row animation.' Im new to the site so i cant upvote sorry when im able to i will come back and do it.

Comment: It is [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; and not [**UItableView** deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

Comment: YA i get the same error along with :unknown receiver, do you mean UITableView?

Comment: Yes dont use UITableView in the function call usr your table object instance instead.